# How convert Fragment to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, dialogfragment

I'm facing a problem to display a fragment through a DialogFragment.
In fact, in my apps I use some fragments in order to display the content of my apps.

For Smartphone, I instantiate directly my fragments in a FrameLayout.
For Tablet, I would display some contents through a DialogFragment. My idea was to reuse my fragments to keep the view and the behavior of it. And Convert it in a DialogFragment to be able to access to DialogFragment behavior.

I tried to create a DialogFragment displaying a FrameLayout used to instantiate my fragments, but this way seems impossible.

I don't find other way to do that.

Someone has solution for this problem?